# PHP variable returning NULL when the row from the SQL query contains data

Tags: php, mysql

I am running an SQL query in PHP but the query returns NULL for one of the fields.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `product_id` = ".$product_id;
$result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $product_name = $row['name'];
            $product_price = $row['price'];
            $product_category = $row['category'];
            $notes = $row['notes'];
            echo $notes;
            $temp_array = array($product_id,$product_name,$product_price,$product_category,$product_quantity,$notes,$current_order,$current_order_id);
            array_push($item,$temp_array);  
        }
```

The field that returns null is notes. I have double and triple checked to see if the field name is notes and whether there was any data in that field. The SQL table looks as follows:
* Note: there is definitely and some text are the strings stored in the table.

```
+ Options
 Full texts 
order_id
product_id
customer_id
quantity
date
notes

Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
96
49
55
12
2016-11-06
there is definitely

Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
104
53
56
3
2016-11-07
some text
```

When i echo all the other fields I recieve the values. The only difference between the fields I can see is that the rest are integer data types and date data types whereas the notes field is varchar (32).

I have echoed the query and run it in PHP my admin and it returns all the data there correctly.

Im not sure what I am doing wrong and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried dumping $row?

Comment: I have and the data is not there

Comment: yes but I am appending it to another array outside of the loop so that isn't an issue.

Comment: Based on the information you've given, either `$row['notes']` is not empty, or `$product_id` is not unique (so you're getting a different row) or it's not not 49 or 53.

Comment: The field definitely has some data in it and the product id is unique. I have rechecked the tables.

Comment: then why not share the `show create table` statements with us?